# how give pagination to controllers

Tags: cakephp

**in controller**

```
public function home($id=null){

    $this->loadModel('Usermgmt.User');

    if(isset($id)){

        $groups=$this->User->findAllByuser_group_id($id);
        $this->set('groups', $groups);

    } else{
        echo 'no id';
        $users=$this->User->find('all');
        $this->set('users', $users);
    }
}
```

here i geeting value which matches the user_group_id and prints  here i am geeting more then 10 users but i need to print only 5 on one page and need to give pagination how to give pagination here

**view**

```
<?php


if (!empty($groups)) {
    // print_r($groups);
    $sl=0;
    foreach ($groups as $row1) {

        //print_r($row1);
        $sl++; ?>
        <div style="width:100%;display:inline-block;">

        <div style="float:left">

            <?php 
            //echo $row1['id'];
            echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('../files/user/photo/'.$row1 ['User']['photo_dir'].'/'.$row1 ['User']['photo'], array('width' => '180', 'height' => '180')),
                array('controller'=>'Profiles','action'=>'index',$row1['User']['id']),
                array('escape' => false));

            ?>

       </div>
       <div>
       <?php echo h($row1['User']['first_name'])." ".h($row1['User']['last_name'])."</br>";
            echo h($row1['User']['username'])."</br>";
            echo h($row1['User']['email'])."</br>";
            echo h($row1['User']['mobile'])."</br>";
            echo h($row1['UserGroup']['name'])."</br>";

        ?></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>


    </div>  

    <?php } 
}?>
```

Comment: you want pagination on view side , by passing paginated data from controller to view right..

Comment: why pagination?.. Use limit... And as @mark suggested you on your other question that not to use magic find method like that `findAllByuser_group_id($id);` if your field is separated by underscore.  Use `findAllByUserGroupId($id);`.

Comment: ya @v2solutions.com exactly

Comment: @FazalRasel in this i need to but button to next page using pagination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Call paginate

The equivalent paginate call to this:

```
$groups=$this->User->findAllByuser_group_id($id);
```

(incidentally - that should be `findAllByUserGroupId`) is this:

```
$groups = $this->paginate('User', array('user_group_id' => $id));
```

### Changing default options

To achieve:

> i need to print only 5 on one page

Modify the paginate property of your controller, e.g.:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $paginate = array('limit' => 5);

    function home($id = null) {
        ... 
        $conditions = array();
        if ($id) {
            $conditions['user_group_id'] = $id;
        }
        $groups = $this->paginate('User', $conditions);
        ...
    }
}
```

### View Modifications

In your view, the pagination helper, and the pagination information will automatically be available by calling paginate as shown above. To get pagination links use [the pagination helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper):

```
echo $this->Paginator->numbers();
```

See [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) for more information and examples of using pagination.

Comment: @thanks for response .. done above way got error as **Indirect modification of overloaded property PagesController::$paginate has no effect [APP\Controller\PagesController.php**

Comment: The error message is because the `$paginate` property didn't exist in your controller. [The pages controller is for rendering static content](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Controller/PagesController.php#L3). While it isn't a code problem to modify it it's an indicator of a poorly structured application. Instead create an action in a more appropriate controller (as shown in the example in the answer) and change [the home route](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/routes.php#L27) to point at it.

Answer (score 0):

As in cakephp pagination can be done using pagination helper of cakephp

In controller action use $this->paginate . From Model return all parameters like fields, conditions and so on in array format , so now in controller you will write

```
$data = $this->ModelName->functionname();

$currentPage = isset($_REQUEST['currentpage']) ? $_REQUEST['currentpage'] : '';

$this->paginate = array(
            'fields' => $data['fields'],
            'conditions' => $data['conditions'],
            'order' => $data['order'],
            'page' => $currentPage,
            'limit' => 25
        );
```

$currentPage is fetched from $_REQUEST['currentpage'];

and finally pass this data to Paginate Helper

```
$data = $this->paginate('ModelName');
```

Now in view you will use Pagination functions as shown below

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('revious'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next'); ?>
```

Comment: `$this->paginate = array(
            'fields' => $data['all'],
            'conditions' => $data[$groups=$this->User->findAllByuser_group_id($id)],
           'order' => $data['desc'],
            'page' => $currentPage,
            'limit' => 3
        );` done like this output limt not working